# How do I get matplotlib to order bar-chart in the same order as my list?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

For a class project I am plotting a barchart. I have a python list with a bunch of labels (even, odd, squares, powers of 3, etc) and a numpy array to hold probabilities associated with each label (in the same order as the labels list). When I plot my chart

`labels = ["even", "odd", "squares", "powers of 3"]`

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(labels, probability)
```

it puts the barchart values in reverse alphabetical order so instead of it being ordered even, odd, squares it is ordered squares, powers of 3, odd, even, etc. How can I keep my plot in the same order as my list?

Comment: As of now, version 2.1.2 of matplotlib, categorical axes will be sorted alphabetically. This is an undesired behaviour, but still has not been fixed, see e.g. [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9318). Probably, [this PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10212) will fix it at some point in the future.  

The only option currently is to plot numbers, just as one had do to prior to matplotlib 2.1 anyways. 

The [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373762/pyplot-sorting-y-values-automatically) shows how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in [`Axes.barh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh.html) is the vertical coordinates of the bars, so you'll want something like

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = np.arange(len(labels))
ax.barh(y, probability)
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

This way, the bars will be ordered following the order of your list from top to bottom. If you want it the other way around, you could simply do

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = np.arange(len(labels))
ax.barh(y, probability)
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

instead.

[image]

Edit: Given @ImportanceOfBeingErnest's comment, I should note that the above was tested with `matplotlib` 2.1.1.

Comment: You may use `ax.invert_yaxis()` to invert the axis, instead of plotting the reversed lists (`[::-1]`), this might make it easier to change e.g. between `barh` and `bar`.

Comment: Ah, useful, let me update the answer to reflect this.