# How to plot the top 5 and bottom 5 of a zipped list in ascending value on the same graph in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, graph, scikit-learn

This is how I created the lists, originally from logistic regression coefs_ and their associated column labels.

```
#Create lists
column_labels = X.columns.tolist()
coef = logreg.coef_.squeeze().tolist()

# Zip together
labels_coef = list(zip(column_labels, coef))

#Sort them and present them as a list
sorted_labels = sorted(labels_coef, key=lambda x: x[1])

#Plotted the bar chart 
plt.barh(*zip(* sorted(sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:],key=lambda x: x[1] )))

#or
#plt.barh(*zip(* (sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:])))

#Show plot
plt.show()
```

But how to print both of them on the same graph in ascending order of value?

Apparently, this does not do the trick

[image]

Comment: how about `plt.barh(*zip(* (sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:])))`?

Comment: do you want to sort them by value?

Comment: @AndreyF yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can append the first five and last five and plot them together:

```
 plt.barh(*zip(* (sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:])))
```

EDIT:
The sorting isue was rased in this question:

[Pyplot sorting y-values automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373762/pyplot-sorting-y-values-automatically)

The 2 suggested solutions there were:

1. plot data as numeric and add y_labels:

> ```
>  labels, values = zip(*(sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:]))
>     plt.barh(range(len(labels)),values)
>     plt.yticks(range(len(values)),values)
>     plt.show()
> ```

2. Bypass the problem by using `pandas`'s `DataFrame`:

   `df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(labels,values))).set_index(1)`

   `df.plot.barh()`

Comment: it seems like you already sorted them here: `sorted_labels = sorted(labels_coef, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: and if you'll plot and sort in the same line?
`plt.barh(*zip(* sorted(sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:],key=lambda x: x[1] )))`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373762/pyplot-sorting-y-values-automatically

Comment: It now gets,  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seq'.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after few days of work, I managed to get it to plot by sorting. There is a pre-step to @AndreyF answer, which using the itemgetter as a key on the operator. The code is as follows.

```
#This will output the top 5, and bottom 5 in sorted form

sorted(sorted_labels[:5], key=operator.itemgetter(1))
sorted(sorted_labels[-5:], key=operator.itemgetter(0))

#Then use the first part of @AndreyF answer

#plotting the list
labels, values = zip(*(sorted_labels[:5] +sorted_labels[-5:]))
plt.barh(range(len(labels)),values)
plt.yticks(range(len(values)),values)
plt.show()
```

[image]