# Custom sorting of categorical variable on x-axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to order the months on x-axis to the order I specify. I have googled extensively, to learn how to do this but to no luck. I am very familiar with R language, and I would do this very easily in R using `factor class` and it's levels. But I am relatively new to python and what I have learned from reading is that `Categorical dtype` in python is the closest to `factor` in R. However, there seems to be a major behavioral difference to these classes in two language. There is no sorting of categorical order when plotted using `pyplot.bar()` but the same plot is ordered correctly in `seaborn` bar plot.

Is there an option for custom ordering of categorical variable in a dataframe for pyplot.bar()?

```
pandas = 0.22.0
matplotlib = 2.1.2
seaborn = 0.8.1



import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype


TestData = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,5,3,5,6,8,9,8,1,2,8,9],'Month':['Jan','Mar','Jan','Feb','May','Apr','Jan','Mar','Jan','Feb','May','Apr','May']})

# Applying custom categorical order
MonthLabels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
M_catType = CategoricalDtype(categories = MonthLabels, ordered = True)
TestData['Month'] = TestData['Month'].astype(M_catType)

plt.bar('Month','value', data=TestData)
```

[image]
[image]

**SOLVED**

May have been an error with the version of matplotlib. I updated the version to 2.2.2 after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373762/pyplot-sorting-y-values-automatically) and everything worked as expected(i.e, axis is sorted to the order provided when setting categories. Also I set the category using the code below,

```
TestData['Month'] = pd.Categorical(TestData['Month'], categories = MonthLabels , ordered = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help; from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#working-with-categories):

> **Note** New categorical data are not automatically ordered. You must explicitly pass `ordered=True` to indicate an ordered `Categorical`.

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. I'll change the code to reflect that

Answer (score 3):

The only way works for me is to set `xunits` to the desired order

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.category import UnitData
TestData = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,5,3,5,6,8,9,8,1,2,8,9],
                         'Month':['Jan','Mar','Jan','Feb','May','Apr','Jan','Mar','Jan','Feb','May','Apr','May']})
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8, 4))
# Applying custom categorical order
MonthLabels = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May']
bar1 = ax1.bar('Month','value', data=TestData)
# set xunits with UnitData
bar2 = ax2.bar('Month','value', data=TestData, xunits=UnitData(MonthLabels))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked 4 me:

```
MonthLabels = ['Feb', 'Mar', 'May', 'June', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
palette = ['#ff9100', '#ad0000']

# Use pd.Categorical to order the columns

df1 = df.copy()
df1['Month'] = pd.Categorical(df1['Month'], categories=MonthLabels)

sns.histplot(data=df1, x='Month', palette=sns.color_palette(palette, 2), hue='Revenue', edgecolor='#FFF', kde=True, legend=True)
plt.suptitle('Distribution of Revenue by Month')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).